# Center second line of href relative to first line and append superscript

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it's possible to center the second line in this example, keeping the href as one href across the two lines, and then append the superscript numbers:

[image]

And what I want to accomplish is:

[image]

I tried applying `display: block;` to the href, but then the superscript part jumps into a new line.

Code:

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;">
<strong><a href="http://example.com/">Firstname Lastname</a></strong> 
<sup>1,3,5,18</sup></p>
```

---Update:
I think I missed something in the question: Lastname should be centered relative to first name, so in this example they have the same length (my bad), but last name should be centered relative to e.g. 'verylongfirstname'.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: strong{float:left}?

Comment: the shift is because of the length of the elements. the second element's length includes the length of <sup>. I guess some margin adjustments can fix it

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is this the solution what are you looking for?

```css
.test {
float: left;
margin-top: ;}

.numb {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<a href="">
  <p>veryverylongfirstname</p>
  <p>lastname</p>
</a>
 </div>
<div class="numb"><p>1,3,5,18</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this one:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yu6vf04/)

you need to remove

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Just add this class to @MKAD's solution. This would make your second link in center relative to the text on first line.                                                 `.test p:last-child {
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: @Warhost but the requirement was that its centered... this removes that.. #justsaying, posted what i think is closer to what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you...?

https://jsfiddle.net/b9sLLqk6/

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;">
  <a href="http://example.com/">
  <span style="display:block">VeryLongFirstName</span>  
  <span style="display:block">Lastname 
     <sup style="position: absolute;">1,3,5,18</sup>
  </span>
  </a>
</p>
```